# Mongoose ValidationError for recently deleted field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

Given the below mongoose Schema, running in Express

```js
const schema = Schema({
  a: {type: String, required: true},
  b: {type: String, required: true}
});
```

I deleted `b: ...`, but now when I post to the express server, mongoose returns:

`"message": "Model validation failed: b: Path 'b' is required."`

So far, I've tried:

- Deleting Mongo's model and then database (just dev for now), as per https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2874
- The server has been restarted, as well as the database service too
- Adding `b` to the post and submitting anyways, which removes the validate error but returns a previous error I had been troubleshooting before encountering this one.
- Changed the database connection URI in mongoose to another, but the error persists.
- Removed and rebuilt `node_modules/` with `rm -rf` and `npm install` with no luck.

Got the idea of removing a cache from [MongoEngine - Deleted field still raises ValidationError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841034/mongoengine-deleted-field-still-raises-validationerror), but so far, I'm not sure **where** or **how** I can clear it (?)

Comment: have you tried strict false? ```const schema = new schema({...}, {strict: false})```

Comment: @DanStarns I just attempted this and the error remains!